# Jena Ontology API via HTTP

Tags: java, http, rest, jena

Apache Jena has Fuseki to access triples via HTTP. But is there any way to access Jena Ontology Api (send commands to it) via HTTP also? I need it because my applications are not written in java so I prefer to use some kind of REST API to communicate with Jena java stuff.

Is there any other solution how to use Ontology API without writing java code?

Answer (score 0):

The Ontology API is just a particular way to access RDF data.  You can do it in SPARQL over HTTP with Fuseki.

Comment: Anyway if I stick to Fuseki and http I can't use reasoners through Inference API right?